# How to configure Squid to return custom error pages based on result of eCAP adapters?

Tags: proxy, configuration, http-proxy, squid, icap

The eCAP adapter is configured in `squid.conf` as:

```
acl bypass_scan_types_req req_mime_type -i ^text/     
acl bypass_scan_types_req req_mime_type -i ^application/x-javascript 
acl bypass_scan_types_req req_mime_type -i ^application/x-shockwave-flash  
acl bypass_scan_types_req req_mime_type -i ^image/ 
acl bypass_scan_types_req req_mime_type -i ^video     
acl bypass_scan_types_req req_mime_type -i ^audio 

acl bypass_scan_types_req req_mime_type -i ^.*application\/x-mms-framed.*$
acl bypass_scan_types_rep rep_mime_type -i ^text/ 
acl bypass_scan_types_rep rep_mime_type -i ^application/x-javascript 
acl bypass_scan_types_rep rep_mime_type -i ^application/x-shockwave-flash 
acl bypass_scan_types_rep rep_mime_type -i ^image/ 
acl bypass_scan_types_rep rep_mime_type -i ^video 
acl bypass_scan_types_rep rep_mime_type -i ^audio 
acl bypass_scan_types_rep rep_mime_type -i ^.*application\/x-mms-framed.*$

loadable_modules /usr/local/lib/ecap_clamav_adapter.so 

ecap_service clamav_service_req reqmod_precache uri=ecap://e-cap.org/ecap/services/clamav?mode=REQMOD bypass=off 
ecap_service clamav_service_resp respmod_precache uri=ecap://e-cap.org/ecap/services/clamav?mode=RESPMOD bypass=on 

adaptation_access clamav_service_req allow !bypass_scan_types_req all 
adaptation_access clamav_service_resp allow !bypass_scan_types_rep all
```

In case of virus detection, adapter returns some virus details and Squid produce default error page. I want to display custom error page instead of default one.

I tried by adding `deny_info` but I don't know exactly how to specify `acl` in this case. The `deny_info` I tried is as:

```
deny_info custom_error.html <my_acl_here>
```

Where `custom_error.html` is exist at `~/ecap/squid-XXXX/errors/en/`. For now, I am not looking for virus details on error page, it could be any static page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution as:

Create a page at `/usr/local/squid/share/errors/templates/ERR_ANY_NAME`. Then add following line at the end of `squid.conf`:

```
deny_info ERR_ANY_NAME clamav_service_req
```

The `clamav_service_req` is same as given in `ecap_service` directive and `ERR_ANY_NAME` is a custom page to display.